# Javascript - Weird parsing URL result

Tags: javascript, xml, wget, http-get

I am trying to download a XML file from a remote site. This is a database site that has information on thousands of products. The general format of the call is:

```
http://data.Icecat.biz/xml_s
3/xml_server3.cgi?prod_id=<prod_id>;vendor=<vendor_name>;lang=<lang>
;output=<output>
```

I am trying to create a javascript to automate this process. The link I am trying it with is in the code below. (I've tried using both wget and http methods)

```
// Dependencies
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// App variables
var file_url = 'https://data.icecat.biz/xml_s3/xml_server3.cgi?prod_id=RJ459AV;vendor=hp;lang=en;output=productxml';
var DOWNLOAD_DIR = './downloads/';

// We will be downloading the files to a directory, so make sure it's there
// This step is not required if you have manually created the directory
var mkdir = 'mkdir -p ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR;
var child = exec(mkdir, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else download_file_httpget(file_url);
});
/*
// Function to download file using wget
var download_file_wget = function(file_url) {

    // extract the file name
    var file_name = url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop();
    // compose the wget command
    var wget = 'wget --http-user="amadman114" --http-password="Chip10" -P ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR + ' ' + file_url;
    // excute wget using child_process' exec function

    var child = exec(wget, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else console.log(file_name + ' downloaded to ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR);
    });
};
console.log(file_url);
*/

// Function to download file using HTTP.get
var download_file_httpget = function(file_url) {
var options = {
    host: url.parse(file_url).host,
    port: 80,
    path: url.parse(file_url).pathname,
    auth: 'MyUsername:MyPassword'
};

var file_name = url.parse(file_url).pathname.split('/').pop();
var file = fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name);

http.get(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
            file.write(data);
        }).on('end', function() {
            file.end();
            console.log(file_name + ' downloaded to ' + DOWNLOAD_DIR);
        });
    });
};
```

However, the code just downloads the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ICECAT-interface SYSTEM "http://data.icecat.biz/dtd/ICECAT-interface_response.dtd"><!-- source: Icecat.biz 2014 --><ICECAT-interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://data.icecat.biz/xsd/ICECAT-interface_response.xsd">
    <Product Code="-1" ID="??" ErrorMessage="Product_id or product partcode should be necessarily specified"  />
</ICECAT-interface>
```

What it should download is the following:

```
<!-- source: Icecat.biz 2014 --><ICECAT-interface xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://data.icecat.biz/xsd/ICECAT-interface_response.xsd"><Product Code="1" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/1198270-HP.jpg" HighPicHeight="400" HighPicSize="47168" HighPicWidth="400" ID="1198270" LowPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/low/1198270-HP.jpg" LowPicHeight="200" LowPicSize="19156" LowPicWidth="200" Name="Compaq 6710b Base Model Notebook PC" Pic500x500="" Pic500x500Height="0" Pic500x500Size="0" Pic500x500Width="0" Prod_id="RJ459AV" Quality="SUPPLIER" ReleaseDate="2007-08-10" ThumbPic="http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/1198270.jpg" ThumbPicSize="4595" Title="HP Compaq 6710b Base Model Notebook PC"><Category ID="151"><Name ID="303" Value="notebooks" langid="1"/></Category><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="269" No="-100"><FeatureGroup ID="0"><Name ID="5073" Value="Technical details" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="35" No="200"><FeatureGroup ID="1"><Name ID="1222500" Value="Processor" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="107" No="180"><FeatureGroup ID="2"><Name ID="1222498" Value="Hard drive" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="106" No="190"><FeatureGroup ID="3"><Name ID="4863" Value="Memory" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="32" No="150"><FeatureGroup ID="4"><Name ID="4865" Value="Optical drive" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="33" No="170"><FeatureGroup ID="5"><Name ID="4867" Value="Display" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="110" No="140"><FeatureGroup ID="9"><Name ID="4977" Value="Audio" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="36" No="110"><FeatureGroup ID="12"><Name ID="4995" Value="Ports & interfaces" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="108" No="30"><FeatureGroup ID="14"><Name ID="5023" Value="Weight & dimensions" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="109" No="55"><FeatureGroup ID="27"><Name ID="5049" Value="Power" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="1403" No="5"><FeatureGroup ID="28"><Name ID="5067" Value="Operational conditions" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="762" No="90"><FeatureGroup ID="31"><Name ID="5075" Value="Keyboard" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="1711" No="120"><FeatureGroup ID="35"><Name ID="5167" Value="Networking" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="2684" No="160"><FeatureGroup ID="45"><Name ID="5641" Value="Video" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="4124" No="178"><FeatureGroup ID="47"><Name ID="8858" Value="Storage" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="6416" No="10"><FeatureGroup ID="67"><Name ID="27423" Value="Packaging data" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="2686" No="50"><FeatureGroup ID="75"><Name ID="27867" Value="Security" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="2687" No="1"><FeatureGroup ID="76"><Name ID="28540" Value="Certificates" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="2933" No="80"><FeatureGroup ID="90"><Name ID="30562" Value="Operating system/software" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="3024" No="130"><FeatureGroup ID="95"><Name ID="31282" Value="Camera" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="7946" No="60"><FeatureGroup ID="143"><Name ID="618812" Value="Battery" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="6417" No="-100"><FeatureGroup ID="146"><Name ID="624346" Value="Other features" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="10674" No="1000"><FeatureGroup ID="148"><Name ID="630457" Value="Design" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="8602" No="160"><FeatureGroup ID="163"><Name ID="764413" Value="Graphics" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="10385" No="65"><FeatureGroup ID="183"><Name ID="1210971" Value="Processor special features" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><CategoryFeatureGroup ID="10675" No="100"><FeatureGroup ID="184"><Name ID="1218765" Value="Performance" langid="1"/></FeatureGroup></CategoryFeatureGroup><EANCode EAN="0882780751682"/><ReasonsToBuy/><ProductBundled/><ProductDescription ID="21805998" LongDesc="" ManualPDFSize="0" ManualPDFURL="" PDFSize="0" PDFURL="" ShortDesc="" URL="" WarrantyInfo="Warranty: HP Services offers limited 3-year and 1-year standard parts and labor warranty, pick-up or carry-in, and toll-free 7 x 24 hardware technical phone support (depending on model); 1-year limited warranty on primary battery. On-site service and warranty upgrades are also available.\n" langid="9"/><ProductFeature Localized="0" ID="47782261" Local_ID="0" Value="1.8" CategoryFeature_ID="73715" CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="35" No="10100050" Presentation_Value="1.8 GHz" Translated="0" Mandatory="1" Searchable="1"><LocalValue Value="1.8"><Measure ID="37"><Signs><Sign ID="21" langid="1">GHz</Sign></Signs></Measure></LocalValue><Feature ID="11379"><Measure ID="37" Sign=""><Signs><Sign ID="21" langid="1">GHz</Sign></Signs></Measure><Name ID="1036524" langid="1" Value="Processor clock speed"/></Feature></ProductFeature><ProductFeature Localized="0" ID="47782291" Local_ID="25156318" Value="Intel Core 2 Duo" CategoryFeature_ID="11560" CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="35" No="10100048" Presentation_Value="Intel Core 2 Duo" Translated="0" Mandatory="1" Searchable="1"><LocalValue Value="Intel Core 2 Duo"><Measure ID="29"><Signs/></Measure></LocalValue><Feature ID="2196"><Measure ID="29" Sign=""><Signs/></Measure><Name ID="11271" langid="1" Value="Processor family"/></Feature></ProductFeature><ProductFeature Localized="1" ID="0" Local_ID="77437771" Value="" CategoryFeature_ID="2727" CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="35" No="100000" Presentation_Value="800; 533 MHz" Translated="0" Mandatory="0" Searchable="0"><LocalValue Value=""><Measure ID="18"><Signs><Sign ID="9" langid="1">MHz</Sign></Signs></Measure></LocalValue><Feature ID="1020"><Measure ID="18" Sign=""><Signs><Sign ID="9" langid="1">MHz</Sign></Signs></Measure><Name ID="3581"..........
```

This suggests that the javascript is passing the URL incorrectly. Ive tried using ampersands and internet code values for the semicolon and ampersands too. 
Any ideas?

**Edit:** Putting this URL directly into any browser works

Comment: What is the resulting URL you send them as seen in the network tab of the console

Comment: A `console.log(file_url);` put at the end of the code still returns the original input URL

Comment: If you copy-paste the URL and open it in a browser window, does it still show the full XML document?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add this, willdo now